# Can you make .htaccess pass PHP parameters

Tags: nginx, litespeed

I'm moving from Nginx to LiteSpeed and I'm struggling to convert this part to .htaccess:

```
    fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     GET;
    fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD_ORG     $request_method;
```

Can I do this with .htaccess? $_REQUEST['REQUEST_METHOD'] must always be GET.

Answer (score 0):

For LiteSpeed enterprise version:

- Set from config: Append `Access-Control-Allow-Methods GET` to a **Virtual Hosts > Context > Header Operations**
- Set from htaccess: Add `Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "GET"`

For LiteSpeed Community version:

- Set from config: Append `Access-Control-Allow-Methods GET` to a **Virtual Hosts > Context > Header Operations**
- Set from htaccess: Add follow example to Not allow POST/OPTIONS/DELETE methods

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(POST, OPTIONS, DELETE) [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
```

Then do a web server graceful restart to take effect.

Feel free to substitute `GET` method to others if you need.